# Would 'seeding' two individual black holes with entangled particles make those two black holes become entangled?

Tags: black-holes, quantum-entanglement

As I understand it from watching some Susskind lectures, if you create two black holes from the same 'pool' of entangled particles, the result can be described by ER and EPR to be a pair of entangled black holes with a subsequent bridge between them..the difference between descriptions provided by ER and EPR being a question of complexity (or lack of).

The questions that come out of this for me are:
1a)could you entangle two existing separate black holes if you created some entangled particles, separated the particles, and then inserted the separated pairs into the two separate black holes? Would that create a bridge (wormhole) between the two black holes?
1b)if so, would that level of entanglement between the black holes become more complex as the black holes aged..in other words, would the level of entanglement evolve at the same pace as the evolution of the black holes..or, if you added more entangled particles to each of the paired black holes, would the complexity of the entanglement increase with the evolution of the black holes. Could this evolution initiate any kind of runaway effect?
2)in a 'freshly entangled' pair of black holes, would querying of the internal state of the black holes via quantum scrambling; as suggested by 
K. A.Landsman, C.Figgatt, T.Schuster, N.M.Linke, B.Yoshida, N.Y.Yao & C.Monroe (https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-019-0952-6), provide a potential access to pass information from the outside of one black hole, to the outside of the other?

Interested dyscalculic layman here..so please try to conceptualise as much as you can.

Comment: In the view of any external observer, nothing ever crosses the horizon in the eternity of time. So black holes cannot be "seeded" with anything - the particles will always remain outside.

Comment: To clarify..as far as I can tell, including emulation there's at least 3 different ways info **might** be taken from beyond the event horizon of a black hole (firewall paradox notwithstanding, of course).   
One of them is referred to in Q2 above.
I realise an outside observer would see alice (or bob) frozen, if alice (or bob) decided to take a nosedive into a blackhole beyond the event horizon.
'Seeding' would be relatively easy. Just shoot the entangled particles at the respective black holes. I'm interested in what the effect would be.

Comment: “*'Seeding' would be relatively easy. Just shoot the entangled particles at the respective black holes.*” - As I stated above, particles would remain outside in any external reference frame.

Comment: You're right, ty. To be sure tho, I don't want to physically extract particles from black holes.
Rather, I want to extract info about entangled particles - using them as medium/probe.
One way of quantifying the area beyond the event horizon was suggested in the paper cited in Q2..and there may be a few other ways too (ie 'third party' 'GHZ state' and emulation).
Anyhow..as ER(=EPR?) bridges are theoretically possible between entangled black-holes (ETBs), I was asking really if it's theoretically possible to 'make' ETBs by chucking entangled particles at them.
A thought experiment, perhaps.

Comment: Hi happy jack - I'm going to ask a question to safesphere @safesphere which might have some relevance. Dear Sir-Safe I was reading a comment exchange you had on another question specifically about how the Universe outside the Observable Universe has no physical relevance to us because it is causally disconnected. It would seem BH's are the same. **Though** entangled particles can exist across both sides of the Cosmic Event Horizon - bringing our sphere back into causal connection - any thoughts?

Comment: No worries BlackholeSlice. Forgive me for butting in, but I'd comment that as far as I know, generally one boundary is much like another in general terms - ie geometry will become more complex the closer to the edge (inside the boundary at least).
Not sure if this is entirely comparative though. My journey is just starting on this topic.
One thought that occurs to me is if there is a similar process occurring on the boundary between our universe and universe beyond our observation, to the proposed Hawking radiation of evaporating black holes.

Comment: @BlackHoleSlice I'm not an expert on entanglement, but they say you can't use it for communication, so there is no causal connection. The cosmic and BH horizons both prevent light from coming back. The difference is that others can "see" you crossing the cosmic horizon, but not the BH horizon. On the other hand, the existence of the cosmic horizon comes from the current cosmological model that is increasingly problematic. In some other models, there is no cosmic horizon and the entire universe is observable.

Comment: Dear Happy Jack, I agree completely. It's just that for the CEH we're on the inside looking out and for BH it's the opposite. Hopefully we'll all learn something. Don't forget to use the @ before a person's name in comments otherwise they won't be notified. For example @safesphere - 10/4 a-ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Watching a Susskind lecture from 2018 (lecture on ER=EPR given at University of California, Santa Barbara), I got a partial answer; re it is conjectured to be possible to entangle two separate black holes by creating bell pairs, separating the pairs of entangled particles, and introducing (one side of) the pairs of entangled particles to each black hole - resulting in a bridge between the two (now entangled) black holes.
This should emulate (create?) a thermofield double state.
Ref: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pY5D7ZgWuXc